# Xamarin tab causes System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement simple tab interface in my Xamarin Android application.
My activity:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
namespace SSMobile
{
    [Activity (Label = "Tabs", MainLauncher = false, Icon = "@drawable/icon",Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity 
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            AddTab ("Panic", Resource.Drawable.tab_icon, new PanicFragment ());
            AddTab ("Diagnostics", Resource.Drawable.tab_icon, new DiagnosticsFragment ());
            AddTab ("Config", Resource.Drawable.tab_icon, new ConfigFragment ());
        }

        protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
            outState.PutInt("tab", this.ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex);

            base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        void AddTab (string tabText, int iconResourceId, Fragment view)
        {
            var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();            
            tab.SetText (tabText);
            tab.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.tab_icon);

            // must set event handler before adding tab
            tab.TabSelected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
            {
                var fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer);
                if (fragment != null)
                    e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);         
                e.FragmentTransaction.Add (Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, view);
            };
            tab.TabUnselected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e) {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(view);
            };

            this.ActionBar.AddTab (tab);
        }

        class PanicFragment: Fragment {
            public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.PanicFragment, container, false);
                return view;
            }
        }

        class DiagnosticsFragment: Fragment {
            public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.DiagnosticsFragment, container, false);
                return view;
            }
        }

        class ConfigFragment: Fragment {
            public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ConfigFragment, container, false);
                return view;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When my app is opening that activity, I get error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

on this line:

```
this.ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
```

Exception log:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at SSMobile.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in c:\Users\darek\Documents\Projects\SSMobile\SSMobile\MainActivity.cs:17
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1944
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.3a5a286c-d028-4989-a49e-efabfb6b0ae6 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x0001f>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: can you please show some more code?

Comment: I've pasted full code.

Comment: have you checked log for exception details??

Comment: I've added exception log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the reason why I wasn't able to use ActionBar.
In my activity, I was using Theme which hides the TitleBar:

```
Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

That makes also ActionBar hidden and not available.
So, if you want to have ActionBar, you cannot use that theme. If you still need to hide titlebar, just add something like:

```
this.ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
this.ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled (false);
```

it will hide app icon and title.

Hope it will save you a few hours of searching :)